# How to create read only email in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, email, ios5

I've written code which creates and populates an email in objective c iOS but we need to ensure the user does not alter the content - the user is still in control of sending the email.
Is this possible and if so how?
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to send the message to the MTA by some means other than the mail framework in iOS. If you use the mail framework, the user will aways be able to edit the message. Two options are:

- Implement your own SMTP client directly in your app. Since you're just sending a message, this isn't really that complicated.
- Send the message to another machine via web services or some other interface, and have that machine send the message on your behalf.

Comment: The SMTP option would often be the approach I would take on other platforms and if someone assures me that this is a reasonable approach on iOS I can follow that route with confidence.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach content as PDF-file

Comment: +1 Good idea, but the user will still be able to edit the message and potentially delete the PDF attachment, so this may not meet the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's no way to do that in the public API.

You can pre-populate the to: addresses, subject, and email body, but the user can always change these if he wants.